# shared-mime-info

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, updates, mime-type

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome Extensions on an ASUS lap-top. On a few occasions recently when updating using the "In built" Software Updater the install hangs on

```
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1)...
```

forcing me to "Kill" the download/install.

What I find I need to do is:- Kill the download/install, reboot (Which seems to always work) then if I try to run Synaptic (Which I also have installed) because the "Updater" tells me a process is running, it requires me to run

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

which seems to fix it.

A further reboot and all seems well. But it is very upsetting never quite knowing if all will come back to normal.

I'd really appreciate some help with this please.
Hal.